# What is exactly P(X) and what is its difference with P(X=x)?

Tags: probability

Apologies for the simple question.

In several sources I found these defitions:

```
1) P(X) represents the probability of X.
2) P(X = x) refers to the probability that the random variable X is equal to a particular value, denoted by x.
```

For example, here https://stattrek.com/probability-distributions/probability-distribution.aspx
I do not understand, however, how do we differentiate between 1) and 2). Pratically, we can only know the probability of X when it assumes some specific value. What would even mean to know the probability of X "in general" as 1) implies?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree, the quote from your link "P(X) represents the probability of X" is confusing. It makes sense only if X is an event, otherwise "probability of random variable" is a meaningless statement.

There are two scenarios where you would see something like $P(X)$:

- When $X$ is an [event](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Event_(probability_theory)), $P(X)$ means probability of $X$ happening, as opposite to probability of it not happening $P(\neg X)$.
- If $X$ is a [random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable), $P(x)$ might be used just as a simplified notation for $P(X=x)$.

In most cases you would know from context which one is it.